# Check how many orders placed with logged in PayPal users

Tags: paypal

During a PayPal checkout, users have the option to login with PayPal or type in their credit/debit card details directly (guest checkout).

Is it possible to see if an order was placed by a user logged in to PayPal vs Guest orders?

Comment: This question doesn't look like a practical, detailed question. Please check out [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If you log in then it will show in your PayPal account activity and you will have buyer protection.

If you pay as a guest buyer it won't show in your PayPal account and you won't have buyer protection *but* as you would have been using a card then your card issuer may help you.